# What is difference between metadata and schema in database?

Tags: database, schema, metadata

First, I want to ask what is the definition of metadata?
Then, what is the difference between the metadata and schema in the database? Whether the data modelling process produces metadata?

Comment: This is sort of a semantics and syntax question where syntax and semantics overlap. I would say the schema describes what your data is and what is constrained to do, if that makes any sense:)

Comment: can give example? I am still confused. thank you for your attention

Answer (score 3):

Schema is the Layout of your Database. E.g, The Table Fields, Definition, Pages, Rows and Columns Etc.

Meta Data is the Data about your Database. Eg If you have a data about all Rap Music, Your meta-data will be: Author, Number of Tracks, Year of release, Location, The Album name, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`Metadata` is 'data about data'. Whereas `Schema` is the structure/layout of the system.

*Real world example for Metadata*: The extra information generated when you take a picture with your phone such as date, location, etc.

*Real world example for Schema*: The layout of a website such us where is the main title, content, etc.

In the context of a database system, **schema is a subset of metadata**.

A database metadata consists of lots of information about its schema, storage, language, security, etc. Whereas a database schema consists of the structure of data in the database such as how the data is organized into tables, rows and columns, etc as well as the relationships and constraints between those data.